# Can not cast value of type to 'UIPageViewController'

Tags: swift3, uipageviewcontroller, ios10, xcode8

So I am new to iOS development. I am trying to make a page swipe functionality like an image carousel or like an app tutorial, and I'm Running into a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. in the log is states  'Can not cast value of type 'ViewController' to 'UIPageViewController'

not sure you need the entire code.

my problem line is:

```
self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contentViewController") as! UIPageViewController
```

help will be greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var pageTitles: NSArray!
var pageImages: NSArray!



override func viewDidLoad() {


    self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: " By Request","Subscription Plan","Flex Plan","Everyday Plan", "Welocme")
    self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "page1","page2","page3","page4","page5")

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contentViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) as ContentViewController

    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: Int(self.view.frame.width), height: Int(self.view.frame.size.height - 60))

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {


}


@IBAction func signupAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {


}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController {

    if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {

        return ContentViewController()
    }

    var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! ContentViewController

    vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
    vc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index] as! String
    vc.pageIndex = index


    return vc

}
// MARK: - Page Vuew Controller Data Source

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil
    }
    index -= 1

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index += 1

    if (index == self.pageTitles.count) {

        return nil

    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)

}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return self.pageTitles.count
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

}

Comment: Where does it happen? Which line?

Comment: self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contentViewController") as! UIPageViewController

Comment: line 25 on mine

Comment: It seems like the view controller with the ID "contentViewController" is not a UIPageViewController. Try to change that in your storyboard.

Comment: now I'm have the same problem but reverse problem with the line of code:     

    var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! ContentViewController

Comment: Thank You  though we have moved to the next problem not a bad thing